# Is dask dashboard history stored somewhere?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Does Dask dashboard have a history like spark-ml has?
I mean does it store the details of the tasks executed on it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest solution may be to use the scheduler's log files, where you have set the chattiness sufficiently high to get the information want (see http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html ).